# Wrapping methods in subclass?

Tags: python, selenium, class

I have a base class driver:

```
class driver(webdriver.Chrome):
    class stack:
        def login(self, login, password):
            pass
        def get_notifications(self):
            pass
    class fb:
        pass
```

I use it to scrape some webapps.
I initialize it:

dr = driver()

I want to pass self to deep functions of wrapped class, so this:

```
dr.stack.login(dr, 'mylogin', 'mypass')
```

Should turn into that:

```
dr.stack.login('mylogin', 'mypass')
```

Is there a way to wrap some methods of a class saving self argument?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Just Refer to this site. for brief its not my code.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factory-method-python-design-patterns/

Might be Factory Pattern will help you in this.

```
# Python Code for factory method
# it comes under the creational
# Design Pattern
 
class FrenchLocalizer:
 
    """ it simply returns the french version """
 
    def __init__(self):
 
        self.translations = {"car": "voiture", "bike": "bicyclette",
                             "cycle":"cyclette"}
 
    def localize(self, message):
 
        """change the message using translations"""
        return self.translations.get(msg, msg)
 
class SpanishLocalizer:
    """it simply returns the spanish version"""
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.translations = {"car": "coche", "bike": "bicicleta",
                             "cycle":"ciclo"}
 
    def localize(self, msg):
 
        """change the message using translations"""
        return self.translations.get(msg, msg)
 
class EnglishLocalizer:
    """Simply return the same message"""
 
    def localize(self, msg):
        return msg
 
def Factory(language ="English"):
 
    """Factory Method"""
    localizers = {
        "French": FrenchLocalizer,
        "English": EnglishLocalizer,
        "Spanish": SpanishLocalizer,
    }
 
    return localizers[language]()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    f = Factory("French")
    e = Factory("English")
    s = Factory("Spanish")
 
    message = ["car", "bike", "cycle"]
 
    for msg in message:
        print(f.localize(msg))
        print(e.localize(msg))
        print(s.localize(msg))
```